Sorting a range of data based on a column within that data
I have a set of data spanning columns A through P in Google Sheets. I would like to add a column in Q that will return the values of A based on the top values of column P. I assume this can be with the Arrayforumla and Sort function but can not figure out that syntax. Any help would be much appreciated.

"I would like to add a column in Q that will return the values of A based on the top values of column P. " It isn't clear exactly what you mean.  Please [edit] the question and include some sample data in markdown text and also an example of your desired result.

To sort column A by column P, use sort(), like this:
=sort(A2:A, P2:A, false)

To get just a limited number of results, use sortn().
See sort() and sortn().
